# Surface integral: approaching this problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate $\iint_{\Sigma} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{\sigma}$, where $$ \vec{F}(x,y,z) = (x,y,z), $$and $\Sigma$ is the closed surface consisting of the curved surface $$\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2=1,\, -1 \le z \le 0\}$$ of a cylinder, bounded on the bottom by the disk $\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\le 1, \, z = -1\}$ and on top by the quadric $z = 1-x^2-y^2$.

[image]

I'm wondering if I have to split this problem in 3 parts: 1) calculate the flux through the cylindrical surface, 2) through the bottom disk and 3) through the quadric, ( 4) adding the results).

I feel like this is a good approach, but I believe the shorter way is to just take the bottom disk as our closed region, which will serve as the domain for a vector function (parameterization) $\vec{\varphi}$. Since our disk can be parameterized easily, we can also quickly determine how to express $z$ in terms of polar coordinates ($z=1-x^2-y^2$).

What I would do:

$z = 1-x^2-y^2$, take $\vec{\varphi}: K \to \Sigma: (\theta,r) \mapsto (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,1-r^2)$. Then, $$ \vec{F} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \vec{\varphi}}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \vec{\varphi}}{\partial \theta} \right) = r^3+r.$$ Giving us $$\iint_{\Sigma} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{\sigma} = \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^1 (r^3+r)dr = \frac32\pi.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The definition of $\Sigma$ seems strange... You are mentioning 3 different surfaces that are stacked.

Comment: I've added an image in my post. I hope it will make the definition clearer.

Comment: Ok, this was useful. This confirms that the spherical surface plays no role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to compute $\iint_{\Sigma} (\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}) d\sigma$. If that is the case, you can just use the divergence theorem and say that
$$
\iint_{\Sigma} (\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}) d\sigma =\iiint_V \textrm{div} \vec{F} dx= 3 vol(V) = \frac{9 \pi}{2}
$$